# como configurar virtual hosts para cakephp en ubuntu server 12.04 LTS con apache 2

Tags: php, apache

Tengo problemas en tener dos app web corriendo en el mismo servidor.
El error que se muestra es:

```
Missing Controller

Error: SchoolController could not be found.

Error: Create the class SchoolController below in file: app/Controller/SchoolController.php

<?php
class SchoolController extends AppController {

}

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_controller.ctp
Stack Trace

    APP/webroot/index.php line 110 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

El archivo de configuracion es el siguiente:

virtual host 1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webapp1/app/webroot

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/webapp1/app/webroot>
         Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride none
         Order deny,allow
            Allow from all

            RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </Directory> 


       #Mod_Rewriter
       RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.php [L]


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

virtual host 2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webapp2/app/webroot

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/webapp2/app/webroot>
         Options -Indexes
            AllowOverride none
         Order deny,allow
            Allow from all

            RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </Directory> 


       #Mod_Rewriter
       RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.php [L]


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Y, ¿cuáles son los problemas que tienes?

Comment: Otra pregunta, ¿por qué piensas que es un problema de configuración de apache y no de tu código php?

Comment: tengo 2 sitios, el primero que pongo en el default si se carga correctamente. El problema es con el segundo sitio que no se carga bien y me dice que hay error al cargar el controlador. No es problema de php mas bien creo que es alguna configuracion que me falta en cakephp porque si el segundo sitio lo pongo como primero en el archivo default de apache si se carga correctamente.

Comment: Es que los dos escuchan la misma ip y el mismo puerto. Cambia el puerto de uno de los dos sitios.

Comment: te refieres en el virtual host??

Answer (score 1):

En general, cada servidor web tiene una identificación única formada por la dirección IP y por el puerto que escucha las peticiones de los usuarios (hay un tercer elemento identificador que es el protocolo). Esto quiere decir que solo puede haber un servidor en cada combinación IP:Puerto.

En tu configuración la primera línea de ambos servidores virtuales

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

dice algo así *"escucha el puerto 80 de todas las direcciones que existan en este servidor"*, estas direcciones pueden ser reales o virtuales. Pero observa, que **ambos escuchan el mismo puerto**.

La segunda línea, de *ambos servidores*, es la siguiente:

```
ServerName localhost
```

que indica la dirección del servidor.

Recuerda que `localhost` no es un nombre cualquiera, se refiere a tu propia máquina con un nombre fácilmente reconocible que corresponde a la IP **127.0.0.1**.

Ahora si, en ambos servidores virtuales tienen la misma dirección y escuchan el mismo puerto:

```
127.0.0.1:80
```

Por eso cuando pides el segundo sitio no puedes ver nada, porque el primero en escuchar la petición es quien la atiende.

La solución es cambiar el puerto del segundo servidor virtual o si tienes otra dirección IP,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost1
  DocumentRoot /var/www/webapp1/app/webroot

  # El resto de directivas
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:88>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost2
  DocumentRoot /var/www/webapp2/app/webroot

  # El resto de directivas
</VirtualHost>
```

En caso que tengas dos direcciones IP en tu servidor, podrás usar el mismo puerto (en este caso 80, que es el estándar), pero tienes que especificar la IP de cada servidor virtual.

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName 10.0.0.1
  ServerAlias localhost1
  DocumentRoot /var/www/webapp1/app/webroot
  # El resto de directivas
</VirtualHost>
```

Recuerda que cambiar el puerto de escucha de tu servidor virtual puede cambiar la programación de tu sitio. Identifica los cambios que necesites hacer.